# Wrong output when using malloc in arrays

Tags: c, arrays

I'm fairly new to c and what I'm trying to do is learn and use malloc and realloc. My program takes an integer x input, then loops until x is met while also taking other integer inputs. I then do various calculations. However my output is 0 when I know it should be something else.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{

    calculations();
}

void calculations()
{

    int i;
    int x;
    int total = 0;
    double squareRoot;
    double overall;

    scanf("%d", &x);

    int* array = malloc(x * sizeof(int));

    if (!array) {
        printf("There isn't enough memory \n");
        return;
    }

    int c = 0;


    while (c < x) {


        scanf("%d", &array[c]);

        total += array[c] * array[c];
        c++;
    }

    squareRoot = sqrt(total);
    array = realloc(array, x * sizeof(int));

    int b = 0;

    while (b < x) {

        overall = array[c] / squareRoot;
        printf("%.3f ", overall);

        b++;
    }
}
```

Comment: `overall = array[c] / squareRoot;` --> `overall = array[b] / squareRoot;`

Comment: why the realloc - its doesnt do anyting

Comment: no functional difference , but the idiomatic names for array indexes are i,j,k not b,c. experienced c programmers will be surprised by b

Comment: also the idiomatic array looping is `for(int i = 0; i < x; i++)` not `while(...)`

Comment: You shouldn't be getting zeros. Put a diagnostic printf after you read the values into array.

Comment: @LookingWest  It is a second question with the same code today.:) Now you have only one attempt in your disposal relative to this program.:)

Comment: @LookingWest  Oh, I am mistaken. It is the third question!:)

Comment: `overall = array[c] / squareRoot;` reads out of bounds (`c == x` at that point which is one past the end)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow if that is true then close as duplicate?

Comment: @M.M It seems he is unable to update all his mistakes in the program using one question.:) The program is too complicated.

Comment: @LookingWest  You should declare the variable total either as long long int or as double.

Comment: The posted code causes the return type from `calculations()` to be `int`.  This is because there is no prototype for that function before the function is actually called.

Comment: when writing an error message, is should be to `stderr`, not `stdout` and when the returned value from a system function indicates an error occurred.  should call `perror()` so the system error message is also output (note: perror() outputs to `stderr` which is what the code should be doing.)

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  (in the current scenario, any returned value except `1` is an error.

Comment: the function: `malloc()` expects a parameter of type `size_t` but in the current scenario  the `x` is type `int` so an implicit conversion is performed. That conversion can change the sign of the result.  It would be better to declare `size_t x;`  and `scanf( "%lu", &x );`   and `size_t c = 0;`

Comment: the function `sqrt()` expect the parameter type to be `double` and the returned type is also `double` however the posted code is passing an `int` parameter   This results in an implicit conversion which the compiler, given some option like `-Wconversion` will complain about.

Comment: this line: `array = realloc(array, x * sizeof(int));` does absolutely noting but enable the possibility of a error to occur.  Strongly suggest removing that line

Comment: suggest replacing: `while( c<x ) ,,, c++;`  with `for( c=0; c<x; c++ )`.  Similar considerations exist for the code block beginning with: `while( b<x )`

Comment: regarding this statement:  `overall = array[c] / squareRoot;`  at this point in the code, the variable `c` is the index one past the end of the array `array[]`.  Accessing one past the end of the array is undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event.  I.E. any value that ends in the variable `overall` is trash